# How do I uninstall xgboost python package?

Tags: pip, xgboost

I have built and installed XGBoost on my system (Ubuntu 16.04) following the [provided instructions](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#python-package-installation). Specifically, I have installed it running

`python3 setup.py install --user`

in its `python-package` directory.

How can I now uninstall it?

When I try with pip3 I get:

`-> pip3 uninstall  xgboost`

`Not uninstalling xgboost at /home/fanta/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost-0.7-py3.5.egg, outside environment /home/fanta/.local/python3.5`

I am using virtualenv under Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages installed manually with `python setup.py install` shouldn't be uninstalled with `pip uninstall`. You have to remove files and directories yourself. Remove `/home/fanta/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost-0.7-py3.5.egg`.

Next time you could install things with `pip install .` in the source code directory.